# Emulator hardware options in ADT 21

Tags: android, configuration, hardware, emulation, adt

**TL;DR: how do I remove support for touchscreen in the emulator, in the new ADT 21? Basically, I want to simulate a (dpad and qwerty)-only device. Details below.**

Neither the new "Device Definitions" nor the "Android Virtual Devices" show a way to edit the hardware, as the [old dialog](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html#createavd) is not available anymore.

Aware of that, I edited the virtual device config.ini file myself, before starting the emulator, to include the `hw.touchscreen` line. It had no effect, and this code:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
    String.valueOf(getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.touchscreen")), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

shows `true`. I suspected this has something to do with the new (to me) `hw.device.name` option, which is related to the new *Device Definitions* tab. And there is a devices.xml file, which includes a touchscreen definition (relevant lines):

```
<d:device>
    <d:name>3.5 nHD</d:name>
    <d:manufacturer>User</d:manufacturer>
    <d:meta/>
    <d:hardware>
      <d:screen>
        <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
        <d:diagonal-length>3.50</d:diagonal-length>
        <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
        <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
        <d:dimensions>
          <d:x-dimension>360</d:x-dimension>
          <d:y-dimension>640</d:y-dimension>
        </d:dimensions>
        <d:xdpi>209.80</d:xdpi>
        <d:ydpi>209.80</d:ydpi>
        <d:touch>
          <d:multitouch>jazz-hands</d:multitouch>
          <d:mechanism>finger</d:mechanism>
          <d:screen-type>capacitive</d:screen-type>
        </d:touch>
      </d:screen>
(...)
```

I've tried just removing the `d:touch` section. Still, no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: If that worked previously, consider filling new bug report at http://b.android.com/ (against Tools)

Comment: It's the first time I try to emulate a device without touch input. Therefore, I'm not even sure it's a bug, especially considering that now they have what looks to be a new, undocumented way to handle configuration for emulated devices.